# Can I avoid memory allocation in C# when writing to a new file?

Tags: c#, .net, buffer, filestream

My application writes to numerous files, and currently we create a new `BinaryWriter` using a new `FileStream` for each file.

The problem is, each `FileStream` will create a new internal buffer on its first write (see [FileStream.cs source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/FileStream@cs/2/FileStream@cs)).

If I could, I'd pool and reuse buffers to avoid the memory churn, but I don't see any way of doing this. Nor do I see any way of reusing a `FileStream` by repurposing it for another file.

Is there any way of doing this? We're using C#/.Net 4.0 for what its worth.

Comment: Are you actually seeing a performance problem here?

Comment: Do you use a non-default buffer size? The default is 4Kb, so it would take a lot of open FileStreams to see an impact on memory.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing 20-30% time spent in GC. We are using 128K buffer size, presumably because someone thought that would give better performance. I'm going to drop that to 4K and reprofile.